# Treasure Fleets vs. Treasure Ships

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In the newest Sid Meier's Pirate! Treasure Ships come in the form of galleons, or indianmen.

Now Some ships have the words TREASURE SHIP above the actual classification of ship. Unfortunately I don't have an exact example but here is a reference.

[image]

The image is that of a Ship of The Line. As you can see the words "New Warship" are listed above the actual classification of "English Ship of the Line".

- So, the question is, what is the cash difference between a Treasure
  Galleon and a Treasure Ship?
- What are the different goods that they carry?
- Are the escorts different per ship?

(Picture from hookedonpirates.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Treasure *Galleon*" is a unique Spanish ship type that has extra cargo room. They'll have the regular types of loot (you can usually deduct what they're carrying by what port they sailed from -- whatever that port/colony normally sells, they'll be carrying it), just more than usual.

A Treasure *Ship* means it's one of the Spanish (treasure) galleons that carries the massive amounts of gold and silver that the Spanish mined/looted from the West Indies back to Spain. They carry a *great* deal of money as well as treasure, usually several thousand at least.

Needless to say, capturing one will make you very rich, your crew very happy, and Spain very annoyed with you.

Comment: What are the differences loot wise?

Comment: If you could explain more about "you can usually deduct what they're carrying by where they sailed from" I'll accept the answer.